# Prophet on google colab return - Error: KeyError: 'metric_file'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, facebook-prophet

today I start to have problems with my colab script that use facebook prophet.
I try to reproduce the error on a basic script.
The problem is at line:

```
m.fit(df)
```

and here you can find the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)<br>
KeyError: 'metric_file'<br>
and the session crashed.<br>
<br>
```

Here you can find complete code:

## Python

```
import pandas as pd

from fbprophet import Prophet

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/master/examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')
df.head()

m = Prophet()

m.fit(df)

forecast = m.predict(future)

forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()

fig1 = m.plot(forecast)
```

Thanks, F.

Answer (score 3):

100% Guaranteed solution!

Install pandas:
`pip install pandas==1.0.4`

Install pystan:
`conda install -c conda-forge pystan==2.19.1.1`

Install fbprophet:
`conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 fbprophet`

Follow the steps and run your code it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to solve the issue.

```
conda install pystan==2.17.1.0
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet==0.6.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Now is fixed buy google.

There is an error in my script, I forgot to insert two lines.  Here you can find working code:

"""
Prophet intro from: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api
"""

## Python

import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet

## Python

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/master/examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')

df.head()

m = Prophet()

m.fit(df)

**future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)

future.tail()**

forecast = m.predict(future)

forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()

fig1 = m.plot(forecast)